# How to manage sessions in NHibernate unit tests?

Tags: nhibernate, nunit

I am a little unsure as to how to manage sessions within my nunit test fixtures.

In the following test fixture, I am testing a repository. My repository constructor takes in an ISession (since I will be using session per request in my web application).

In my test fixture setup I configure NHibernate and build the session factory. In my test setup I create a clean SQLite database for each test executed.

```
    [TestFixture]
public class SimpleRepository_Fixture
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private static Configuration _configuration;

    [TestFixtureSetUp] // called before any tests in fixture are executed
    public void TestFixtureSetUp() {
        _configuration = new Configuration();
        _configuration.Configure();
        _configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(SimpleObject).Assembly); 
        _sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    [SetUp] // called before each test method is called
    public void SetupContext() {
        new SchemaExport(_configuration).Execute(true, true, false);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_add_new_simpleobject()
    {
        var simpleObject = new SimpleObject() { Name = "Object 1" };

        using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            var repo = new SimpleObjectRepository(session);
            repo.Save(simpleObject);
        }

        using (var session =_sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            var repo = new SimpleObjectRepository(session);
            var fromDb = repo.GetById(simpleObject.Id);

            Assert.IsNotNull(fromDb);
            Assert.AreNotSame(simpleObject, fromDb);
            Assert.AreEqual(simpleObject.Name, fromDb.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a good approach or should I be handling the sessions differently?

Comment: Technically, it might be better to start with a totally clean state on every unit test (new configuration before each test), but it will take too long to run a lot of tests on that way, so I use something very similar like your version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks pretty good, but I would create as a base class.  Check out how Ayende does it.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/28/nhibernate-unit-testing.aspx

Comment: In this base class Ayende is creating the db once for all tests. I read that it is better to do this once per test. Is this still possible through the base class?

Comment: I've just implemented this base class and it's actually very good. Definitely recommended.